# Zurb Foundation 4 SCSS mixins for small and large(fluid/responsive) columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm building a company responsive website and using both SASS and Foundation 4 CSS Framework for the first time. So far so good. 
However I'm having a "problem" here with mixins. 
If I want a column with size 6 in large views and size 3 in small views, I can use built-in CSS classes

```
 class="large-6 small-3 columns"
```

Is there any way to do this via a Foundation SASS mixin? The only mixin for columns I found [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html) is

```
@include grid-column($columns, $last-column, $center, $offset, $push, $pull, $collapse, $float);
```

And for what I get, I cannot specify veiwports here.

Any thoughts?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made some mixins to make easier to deal with that:
https://gist.github.com/jofralogo/5324278

```
@mixin rgrid($phone-grid:"",$desktop-grid:""){
    @extend .small-#{$phone-grid};
    @extend .large-#{$desktop-grid};
    @extend .columns;
}
```

This mixin provides an easy way to use the F4 grid classes and media-queries.

- $phone-grid: number of grid columns.
- $desktop-grid: number of grid columns that overrides $phone-grid for window width 768px and above.
- Only one parameter could be declared to define a value for every window width.

i.e.:

```
@include rgrid(3,6); => 3 columns for phone, 6 columns for desktop.
@include rgrid(6); => 6 columns.
```

Comment: I wish that the extend solution was bulletproof, but it isn't. [Foundation uses attribute selectors](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/scss-standalone/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss#L145-L146) that can't be extended in this way. Here's an example of why it doesn't work: http://cdpn.io/faHey

Comment: I really like your approach though, since it cuts down on CSS duplication. I've raised the issue with the Zurb team. If you're concerned about semantics, chip in your opinion here: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3049

Answer (score 3):

I think you could get that by `@extend` a Foundation class instead of `@include` a Foundation mixin. That way you get everything that Foundation built into their grid classes, as well as the ability to stack them.

Assign the classes you want in the CSS:

```
.my-super-semantic-div {
    @extend .large-6, .small-3, .columns;
}
```

Instead of in the HTML:

```
<div class="large-6 small-3 columns">...<div>
```

Comment: Apparently you can't. The SCSS compiler says: _Can't extend .small-4 .columns: can't extend nested selectors_

Comment: You can make it work with a comma between the classes. `@extend .large-6, .small-3, .columns;`

Answer (score 2):

> But what I wanted to know was if they have a built-in SASS mixin for this. However I'll check their @media settings and try to implement it myself.

Nope, they don't. :( See documentation: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html

But you don't need to invent anything! Just use the beautiful [respond-to](https://github.com/snugug/respond-to) Compass extension by [Snugug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703084/snugug).

In addition to calling media queries by names as described in respond-to's readme, you can fire them by their numbers.

Example in the clean indented syntax:

```
// Declaring the breakpoint ranges
$breakpoints: 'xs' (0 400px), 's' (401px 600px), 'm' (601px 800px)

// Declaring a function to retrieve a breakpoint by number
@function bp($number)
  @return nth(nth($breakpoints, $number),1)

// Calling a media query traditionally by a name
.bar
  +respond-to('s')
    @include grid-column(6)

// Calling a media query by its number
.foo
  +respond-to(bp(2))
    @include grid-column(6)
```

Yay!

Answer (score 1):

FOr these things you should use semantic classes.

`class="something-descriptive"`

and in your sass include different mixins for different sizes, something like this:

```
.something-descriptive {
    @include grid-column(3)
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .something-descriptive {
        @include grid-column(6)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what I wanted to know was if they have a built-in SASS mixin for this. However I'll check their @media settings and try to implement it myself.

Comment: They do and they do not: they don't have anything explicit like `@include small-grid-column(6)`, but they do offer variables, so that one could write `@media #{$small} { .something-descriptive { @include grid-colum(6) } }`  --  read at the end here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html

Answer (score 1):

With the Sass Mixins you have to use media queries to explicitly change the grid. The way I approached this is to do a Mobile First site, then to duplicate the Sass code that defines the grid into 2 media queries like so:

```
// Mobile Grid
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { ... }
// Desktop & Tablet Grid
@media #{$small} { ... }
```

I couldn't find any clear examples of how this works. From what I gathered you should be able to define the grid in Sass and then override it with only the `@media #{$small} {}` media query, however in practice I could not get it to work. I tried having the media query before the other grid, after, etc and what the result was is that the first time you set the grid is the way it stays.

Here is a longer example. In the case of the `#dashboard` it is stacking and centered on mobile and 3 column on desktop / tablet. This would be `class="small-10 small-centered large-4 columns"` for using presentational classes.

```
// Mobile Grid
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #dashboard { @include grid-row;
    & > #stats { @include grid-column(10, false, true); }
    & > #records { @include grid-column(10, false, true); }
    & > #results { @include grid-column(10, false, true); }
  }
}

// Desktop & Tablet Grid
@media #{$small} {
  #dashboard { @include grid-row;
    & > #stats { @include grid-column(4, false, false); }
    & > #records { @include grid-column(4, false, false); }
    & > #results { @include grid-column(4, false, false); }
  }
}
```

NOTE: you could expand upon this and have more breakpoints using the mixins but this seems to simulate the default Zurb F4 presentational class behavior.